# Web-services with real-time data transfer

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, rest, azure

I'm developing an Android application that is intended to show the GPS location of a radio controlled toy car. The way I was thinking of doing this is using some kind of web-service to hold the position of the car, that has a GPS and some GSM SIM. The mobile app can retrieve the data from the web-service.

Is it possible to use web-services for real-time data transfer as well?
Let's say that I want the mobile application to get data as soon as a change has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "real-time" and "as soon as a change has been made".  I work on smart camera's at work that run on assembly lines with 60 unit a second rates (and faster).  I work on hobby robots at home that need to be accurate in their movements to within a few millimeters.  Both of these are considered "real-time" by some group of people, but they are about 100x different in terms of tolerance.  So the question is what are your actual needs.
  Even better is how does one decide for oneself. :-)  Turn around time for communications is an obvious gating factor.  You also have to consider processing time on the server which is tied to the server hardware and the amount of demand.  A quite server on a modern wireless Ethernet network is going to be in the 10 millisecond range (there are lots of reasons for this to vary).  Is that quick enough?  What will your server be doing to retrieve the information (Is there a file read involved? a Database?)  Is the server not a PC? (embedded platforms typically have fewer resources)  What is the client doing with the GPS information?  Reporting the position is probably fine.  Land navigation is probably fine (though the trip time will be longer over a cell network).  Fine grain navigation is not going to work with these kind of response times, but GPS doesn't have the resolution to make that work anyway.
  Hope this gives you an idea of the variables that you need to consider.  Let us know what you decide and more importantly why. :-)

Comment: I was thinking of something similar to this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WOBNheiXbMQ   As you can see the data seems to be updated almost immediately. Hope this answers it.

Comment: I've tried using Microsoft Azure and I noticed that the time it takes to write and retrieve data takes quite a while. This is way I wanted something that takes less than 500 ms atleast

Comment: Transport time is going to kill you.  Not sure what cell network you are on but the times are long and very variable.  Still it will likely be good enough for hobby use.  Azure uses shared servers so now you are fighting a second battle for determinism.  The server may be busy with other requests for significant portions of a second before it gets back around to yours.  It seems like this will be a poor choice for the processing itself.  Storage of the answers sure, but retrieval times are going to be very variable and slower than you would like.

Comment: I understans that cell networks usage for this may not be the best solution. Using Bluetooth or similar solutions on the other hand results in another problem, that I have to be fairly close to the toy car. Any suggestions on tech to use to solve it ?

Comment: There are a number of variables here.  How will the car be used?  Is this a toy?  The trick is alternatives require setup.  If the vehicle is operating in a fixed area a Wireless Ethernet network could be used but you would have to setup the network.  I guess I don't have a clear enough idea of what you are trying to build to suggest alternatives.  The cell solution will work, but it will not be fast (sub second) on updates.

Answer (score 0):

An Azure web role instance with 1 core can easily record incoming geo-positioning data at speeds over 1000/sec.  There are many ways to record the data - both persistent and non-persistent.  Windows ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) can record information like this at over 100x this rate.  And you can use this on Azure compute instances.  More important is how you digest the incoming stream, summarize, and send down to your mobile client.  Again, many ways to do this very doable with an Azure backend plus Azure Mobile Services, for example.

My code for this used a standard asp.net MVC 5 webapi template.  I ingested a simple JSON doc with geo-positioning data (load tested up to 1400/sec) and wrote it to Azure blob storage using ETW.  As you get further along, ask for details.